# Collecting futures==3.2.0 failed in Deploy python flask app into Heroku

Tags: python, python3, heroku

I am new to Heroku and I am trying to deploy a python flask app into Heroku, but in doing so, I got the message:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement futures==3.2.0 (from -r /tmp/build_b6e63e1db9605f37d761ae7a911fd5b1/requirements.txt (line 7)) (from versions: 0.2.python3, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 2.2.0, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.1.0, 3.1.1)

I am trying with Python 2.7 and 3.7 version, but I still get the same error. Can any one advise me on this?

Answer (score 0):

The current version of `futures` is apparently `futures 3.3.0` [according to PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/futures/). You can get older copies of `futures` from the project's [GitHub release page](https://github.com/agronholm/pythonfutures/releases).

Hypothetically speaking, you should be able to download the correct `.zip` file (e.g. `pythonfutures-3.20.zip`), upload/extract in on your platform and run the `setup.py` installation file with ex. `python setup.py install`.

That said, I am unsure that Heroku allows this currently, so you may need to find another way to get `futures 3.2.0` installed.